# Create persistent key using two unique id's as the source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, key, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

I'm extracting data from a system that is using uniqueidentifier as the field type for it's primary keys.

On the system I'm extracting from, I've been given access to a single table that's been derived.  That table has been made by joining one table to a one to many table resulting in me needing to use two of these uniqueidentifier columns to get uniqueness.

Is there a way for me to create a simple persistent key using these two columns?

The only idea I have at the moment is to create an identity column on my table, and upsert any future extractions (daily) into my table.

Is there a better method than this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add what is known as a 'composite key'.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourtablename 
ADD CONSTRAINT uq_yourtablename UNIQUE(column1,column2);
```

Comment: Will that add a new column to my table?

Comment: No, it will just add a constraint to the table which confirms that each row is unique - based on a combination of the "GUIDs" in the unique identifier columns. Before you run the statement, replace "column1" with the name of the first unique-identifier column and "column2" with the name of the second. If the table already has duplicates then the constraint will not set up on the table until you de-dupe it. Once you have set up the constraint, the table will not allow duplicates to be loaded.